# How can I pass in constructor arguments when I register a type in Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have the following type being registered in Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>, AzureTable<Account>>();
```

The definition and constructors for AzureTable are as follows:

```
public class AzureTable<T> : AzureTableBase<T>, IInitializer where T : TableServiceEntity
{

    public AzureTable() : this(CloudConfiguration.GetStorageAccount()) { }
    public AzureTable(CloudStorageAccount account) : this(account, null) { }
    public AzureTable(CloudStorageAccount account, string tableName)
            : base(account, tableName) { }
```

Can I specify the constructor arguments in the RegisterType line? I need to be able to pass in the tableName for example.

This is a follow-up to my last question. That question was I think answered but I didn't really clearly ask how to get the constructor arguments in.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is an MSDN page describing what you require, [Injecting Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx). Take a look at using the `InjectionConstructor` class in your register type line. You will end up with a line like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>, AzureTable<Account>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(CloudStorageAccount)));
```

The constructor parameters to `InjectionConstructor` are the values to be passed to your `AzureTable<Account>`. Any `typeof` parameters leave unity to resolve the value to use. Otherwise you can just pass your implementation:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount();
container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>, AzureTable<Account>>(new InjectionConstructor(account));
```

Or a named parameter:

```
container.RegisterType<CloudStorageAccount>("MyAccount");
container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>, AzureTable<Account>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<CloudStorageAccount>("MyAccount")));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could give this a try:

```
// Register your type:
container.RegisterType<typeof(IAzureTable<Account>), typeof(AzureTable<Account>)>()

// Then you can configure the constructor injection (also works for properties):
container.Configure<InjectedMembers>()
  .ConfigureInjectionFor<typeof(AzureTable<Account>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(myConstructorParam1, "my constructor parameter 2") // etc.
  );
```

More info from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650036.aspx).